# how to convert and capture with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to upload a video.Uploaded video will be capture two images at 10% and 50% time length.
And if uploaded video is not flv, want to convert to flv.
How to know uploaded video is flv or not flv.
How to convert?
Now I am using php and ffmpeg.
Please someone answer me.I am beginner for php, ffmpeg and english language.
I founded many questions in this website about ffmpeg.But I can't found need answer.
If this question is duplicate question,forgive me.

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Comment: I have learned ffmpeg documentation at last week.But it is not easy to understandard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to know uploaded video is flv or not flv

You can use backtick (`) operator and invoke `file` command there to check if its a `flv` file

```
if(stripos(`file Hum-Hain-is-pal-yaha.flv`, "Macromedia Flash Video")!==false){
    // gotcha 
}
```

And according to [this tutorial](http://www.99points.info/2010/06/codeigniter-tutorials-convert-video-to-flv-using-ffmpeg/). You can convert any video to `.flv` just by following command.

```
 `ffmpeg -i $input_video_path {$ouput_video_path}.flv`
```

**Note:** the backtick (`) operator.

Comment: Thank Shiplu ,Now I will try As your way